# CakePHP 3 Multiple Databases

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to connect to a second (remote) database using CakePHP 3. I have found solutions online that suggest how to associate different models with different databases but that is not what I need to achieve.

I need to be able to connect to a remote database (that is not associated with any model) and read/write some records from an action in my controller. Can this be achieved using CakePHP?

**Edit (more information):**

I have a website that acts as a booking platform for hotel rooms. The availability of these rooms can be controlled via my website and stored in my database. But for some clients I want to be able to connect to their private database directly and use their records to check availability.

Comment: If you need to write in a table in a database you might as well create a Model for it... I don't understand the "that is not associated with any model" part. It may not be part of your main data structure but it is still structured data.

Comment: @JvO Thanks for your response! Here is the thing. I have a website that acts as a booking platform for hotel rooms. The availability of these rooms can be controlled via the website and stored in my database. But for some clients I want to be able to connect to their private database directly and use their records to check availability. Would I need to create a custom model for each client?

Comment: Don't these clients offer an api you can access? Why would you be querying the database directly? Just curious

Comment: That, or at least one model per type of booking software (I hope that some clients at least use the same software package). This is also necessary since I assume the exact query will vary a lot between systems.

Comment: @yBrodsky Unfortunately they don't and I don't have the time to create a unique API for each of my clients. Hence the direct connection. Not ideal but the only solution I could come up with.

Comment: @JvO Ok, thanks a lot!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple database connection in cakephp 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29981890/multiple-database-connection-in-cakephp-3)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Follow the Below Instructions**

> **Step 1 :** Open `config/app.php` Find `Datasources` array and add `Remote Database` configuration like as -

```
'Datasources' => [
    'default' => [
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => 'localhost',
        'port' => '3306',
        'username' => 'YOUR_DB_USER',
        'password' => 'YOUR_DB_PASS',
        'database' => 'YOUR_DB_NAME',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => false,
        'log' => false,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ],
    'remote_db_1' => [ /*Remote Database 1*/
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '192.168.1.47', /*YOUR_REMOTE_SERVER_IP*/
        'port' => '3306',
        'username' => 'REMOTE_DB_USER',
        'password' => 'REMOTE_DB_PASS',
        'database' => 'REMOTE_DB_NAME',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => false,
        'log' => false,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ],
   'remote_db_2' => [ /*Remote Database 2*/
        'className' => 'Cake\Database\Connection',
        'driver' => 'Cake\Database\Driver\Mysql',
        'persistent' => false,
        'host' => '192.168.1.47', /*YOUR_REMOTE_SERVER_IP*/
        'port' => '3306',
        'username' => 'REMOTE_DB_USER',
        'password' => 'REMOTE_DB_PASS',
        'database' => 'REMOTE_DB_NAME',
        'encoding' => 'utf8',
        'timezone' => 'UTC',
        'flags' => [],
        'cacheMetadata' => false,
        'log' => false,
        'quoteIdentifiers' => false,
        'url' => env('DATABASE_URL', null),
    ],
```

> **Step 2 :** Now you can access `Remote database` in your controller like as-

```
use Cake\Datasource\ConnectionManager;
use \PDO;

class YourController extends AppController{
    public function getRemoteData(){
      $conn1 = ConnectionManager::get('remote_db_1'); #Remote Database 1
      $conn2 = ConnectionManager::get('remote_db_2'); #Remote Database 2
    }
}
```

> **Note:** Now you can use `PDO` methods to Insert,Retrieve,Update

**Example :**

```
class YourController extends AppController{
    public function getRemoteData(){
      $conn1 = ConnectionManager::get('remote_db_1'); #Remote Database 1
      $sql   = "SELECT * FROM  users";
      $query = $conn1->prepare($sql);
      $query->execute();
      $result = $query->fetchAll(); #Here is the result
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic! Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!